# What does the authentication_handler do in FosUserBundle/Symfony

Tags: security, symfony

What is the following line doing in security.yml file?

```
 security: firewalls: main: logout: success_handler: authentication_handler
```

I have been looking for hours in both Symfony file and FOSuserbundle but cannot find any services with **authentication_handler** in it. Maybe someone could tell me where to find the service and the class associated with it.

I would like to adapt it so that when I log out:

- I am redirected to the default page of my web site (if I logged out from a restricted area which needs authentication).
- I stay on the current page (if the current page from which at logged out doesn't request any authentication)

Comment: What `security.yml` is that? Your own? Some bundle's? FOSUserBundle uses .xml files for configuration so I don't know what are you actually talking about.

Comment: # app/config/security.yml

Comment: So this is your own config file, and that means, you should know why that line is there. It's not added automatically. You had to put it there manually. Did you grep your source code for `authentication_handler`?